# How are uncaught runtime exceptions logged with log4j and jboss?

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, uncaught-exception

As far as I know, it is possible to handler uncaught exceptions with `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

However, is it possible to enable it with Jboss and Log4j configuration file instead?

If no configuration is required, do all uncaught exceptions will be logged automatically to my default appender, says `server.log`

Answer (score 0):

Yes uncaught exceptions should be logged. Assuming the default logging configuration these would end up on the console and in the `server.log`. Note that the `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` is used when a thread terminates due to an exception. It's not really about catching any uncaught exception.

Another thing to note is WildFly and JBoss EAP do not use log4j for their log manager. I assume you're referring to one of these given the `jakarta-ee` tag.

Comment: Yes totally agree that uncaught exceptions should be logged. However, I don't know how to configure it in a jboss and log4j environement. 

I am still using Jboss 4.2.

Comment: Given this comment I'm going to remove the `jakarta-ee` tag. I don't know much about JBoss 4.x. However I would imagine it would log uncaught exceptions. Though the exception would need to be truly uncaught and fall through to some server code.